# MySQL query for employee hierarchy

Tags: mysql

Need a simple mysql query to know the subordinate employee in a organisation.
I have created a table which looks as shown below:

```
emp_code    level    reporting_to
emp001      0        emp001
emp002      1        emp001
emp003      2        emp002
emp004      3        emp001
emp005      3        emp003
emp006      3        emp003
emp007      3        emp001
```

I need a query using which, I can know the subordinate employees of a given employee, by giving the employee code.

For example, for **emp001** all employees will be displayed, for ***emp002*** will list *emp003*, *emp005*, *emp006* and for ***emp003*** only *emp005*, *emp006* will be displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you had shown us an actual query where you were stuck, you could have gotten an answer.  But as it stands now, your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Hi Tim, the query **select @pv:=reporting_to as category_id, emp_code, level from `user`
join
(select @pv:='emp002')tmp
where reporting_to=@pv**